# How to find the duplication entry of mobile no using php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I have created the form with multiple form field. Based on selection i show and hide the form field. How to validate the duplicate entry of mobile no.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#hidden-div').hide();
  $("#select_btn").change(function() {
    toggleFields();
  });

});

function toggleFields() {
  var selectVal = $("#select_btn").val();
  if (selectVal <= 5) {
    $hiddenHtml = $('#hidden-div').clone().html();
    $("#refer").html('');
    for (var i = 0; i < selectVal; i++) {
      $("#refer").append($hiddenHtml);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <head>
    <title> Demo </title>
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow" />
    <form id ="refer-form" name="refer-form" action="validate.php"  method="post" >

      <p>No of Referrer:
        <select id="select_btn" >
          <option value="0">--Select--</option>
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
          <option value="3">3</option>
          <option value="4">4</option>
          <option value="5">5</option>
        </select>
      <div id="hidden-div">
        <div id="text">Referrer</div>
        <p>Name:
          <input type="text" name="name[]" />
        </p>
        <p>Mobile:
          <input type="text" name="mobile[]" />
        </p>
        <p>Email:
          <input type="text" name="email[]" />
        </p>

      </div>
      <div id="refer">

      </div>
      <p align="center">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </p>
    </form>
```

For  example user select No of referrer option is 2 and then i show the form field 2 time.... I need to avoid  duplication of mobile entry....

If the user enter same mobile no again then i throw the error "please enter the valid mobile no mobile is already enter."

Comment: use `jquery custom validate`

Comment: any give any example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Way 1 :** Loop through all the mobile number fields and check whether any mobile number is previously occupied or not using `$.inArray` function of jquery.

Please check below snippet.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#hidden-div').hide();
  $("#select_btn").change(function() {
    toggleFields();
  });

});

function toggleFields() {
  var selectVal = $("#select_btn").val();
  if (selectVal <= 5) {
    $hiddenHtml = $('#hidden-div').clone().html();
    $("#refer").html('');
    for (var i = 0; i < selectVal; i++) {
      $("#refer").append($hiddenHtml);
    }
  }
}

$("#refer-form").on('submit',function(){
  var phoneNumber = [];
  $("input[name='mobile[]']").each(function(){
    var _phoneno = $(this).val();
    if($.inArray(_phoneno,phoneNumber) === -1){
      if($.trim(_phoneno)){
        phoneNumber.push(_phoneno);
      }
    }else{
      alert("Mobile number is already exist");
      return false;
    }
  });
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "validate.php",
    data:$(this).serialize(), 
    cache: false,
    success: function(data){
      console.log(data);
    }
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
<title> Demo </title>
<meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow" />
<form id ="refer-form" name="refer-form" action="validate.php"  method="post" >
 
  <p>No of Referrer:
    <select id="select_btn" >
      <option value="0">--Select--</option>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
    </select>
    <div id="hidden-div">
 <div id="text">Referrer</div>
      <p>Name:
        <input type="text" name="name[]" />
      </p>
      <p>Mobile:
        <input type="text" name="mobile[]" />
      </p>
      <p>Email:
        <input type="text" name="email[]" />
      </p>
      
    </div>
    <div id="refer">

    </div>
    <p align="center">
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </p>
</form>
```

**Way2:** Use `.map` function to get all mobile number and using `hasDuplicates` function check array having any duplicate values or not.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#hidden-div').hide();
  $("#select_btn").change(function() {
    toggleFields();
  });

});

function toggleFields() {
  var selectVal = $("#select_btn").val();
  if (selectVal <= 5) {
    $hiddenHtml = $('#hidden-div').clone().html();
    $("#refer").html('');
    for (var i = 0; i < selectVal; i++) {
      $("#refer").append($hiddenHtml);
    }
  }
}

$("#refer-form").on('submit',function(){
  var phoneNumber = [];
  var phoneNumber = $("input[name='mobile[]']").map(function(){if($.trim($(this).val()))return $(this).val();}).get();
  if(hasDuplicates(phoneNumber)){
    alert("mobile number is already exist");
    return false;
  }else{
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "validate.php",
      data:$(this).serialize(), 
      cache: false,
      success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
      }
    });
  }
});

function hasDuplicates(array) {
  var valuesSoFar = Object.create(null);
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
    var value = array[i];
    if (value in valuesSoFar) {
      return true;
    }
    valuesSoFar[value] = true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
<title> Demo </title>
<meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow" />
<form id ="refer-form" name="refer-form" action="validate.php"  method="post" >
 
  <p>No of Referrer:
    <select id="select_btn" >
      <option value="0">--Select--</option>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
    </select>
    <div id="hidden-div">
 <div id="text">Referrer</div>
      <p>Name:
        <input type="text" name="name[]" />
      </p>
      <p>Mobile:
        <input type="text" name="mobile[]" />
      </p>
      <p>Email:
        <input type="text" name="email[]" />
      </p>
      
    </div>
    <div id="refer">

    </div>
    <p align="center">
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </p>
</form>
```

Comment: hi rahul, it working but when i click submit button the record was insert into database... how can i stop here,user change no then only i sent it too db

Comment: Make return false at the end of submit button. Let me change in my script.

Comment: @sakthi Hi check now. It will not form submit now any more because I have return false in the .on('submit' event.

Comment: submit function not working after change mobile no.... How can i do this

Comment: The form is not submitting because we have placed return false in submit event.

Comment: When phone is already exist you will get alert and when there are unique phone number for every phone field then allow to form submit by removing return false and the form will submit.

Comment: validate.php is ajax file. where you submit your form data?

Comment: You can make ajax call in the else part and submit all the form data by $("#refer-form").serialize();

Comment: <?php $name= $_POST['name'];
$mobile= $_POST['mobile'];
$email= $_POST['email'];for($i = 0; $i < count($name); ++$i) {$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "test");   if($link === false){
     die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
 }    $sql = "INSERT INTO test1 (name,email,mobile) VALUES ('$name[$i]','$email[$i]', '$mobile[$i]')";
 echo "$sql";
 if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
     echo "Records added successfully.";
 } else{
     echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
 } mysqli_close($link);
 }
?>

Comment: how can i call the ajax and where i call

Comment: Please check updated snippets I have placed ajax call code in both sample snippet.

Comment: how can i send mail with this form fields

Comment: You can write mail sending code in validate.php file. This file has been called by ajax call and you will get form fields in $_POST.

Comment: hi rahul, i write the code and sending mail working fine. But  form value is insert twice in db. How to reset the cache after success

Comment: Same record inserting twice in DB? And mail are sending once or twice?

Comment: How to check the duplication in name